# Visual basic 6: wait for called program end

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wait for a shell process to finish before executing further code in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685972/how-to-wait-for-a-shell-process-to-finish-before-executing-further-code-in-vb6)

I'd like to write program that will generate text file, process it with another one and then load results.

As I'm experimenting the code is slightly different:

```
Main.Command2.Enabled = False
Shell "foobar.exe =bar.txt +" & "foo.txt", vbMinimizedNoFocus
Main.Command2.Enabled = True
Kill "bar.txt"
```

and the `bar.txt` file still remains in the directory and `foobar`'s testing routine doesn't throw error that `bar.txt` exists.

How can I force my program to wait until `foobar.exe` finishes?

Resolved at [How to wait for a shell process to finish before executing further code in vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685972/how-to-wait-for-a-shell-process-to-finish-before-executing-further-code-in-vb6)

Comment: This isn't really a "call" as such, just running a child process. Do you really want to do a synchronous wait here though? Almost defeats the purpose of using a child process. You could use a Timer to poll the child for completion though, it is very similar to a sync wait with only slight changes.

Comment: @Bob: Problem is that this program is written in c++ and is closed. `foo` file is only set of input parameters and `bar` is same as screen output. And timer is also useless because I do not know how long the `foobar` will work.