# Visual Studio 6.0 and Git (source control)

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, vb6, ide

I have a project developed years ago with VS 6.0, and I want to make some changes. I have installed Visual Studio IDE (6.0), but I want - and I have - to control the source code of this project, with GIT, or another source version control.

Do you have any idea of how can I do this? or, Do you know a plugin for VS 6.0 and GIT (or another one)? Or should I control this code directly with the folder and Git Bash (command line)?

Any comment, suggestion, or advice is welcomed!

Comment: See also the [general question about GIT and VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462480/using-git-with-vb6)

Comment: @MarkJ actually I saw that post before I write this question, but it helps, not to resolve my problem but to understand other things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Git with VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462480/using-git-with-vb6)

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in support for Git in VS 6.0 but you can use Git with it just fine. (You can use any source control system with any version of VS - it may not be integrated into the IDE but it'll work.)

If you prefer the Git command-line, use that. If you prefer using a GUI tool, one of them is SourceTree or TortoiseGit. I'm sure there are others, too.

As you're making changes in the project, when you're ready to commit things, just switch to the command-line (or the GUI tool) and perform the source-control operations you need. In Tools->Options (or Settings, I don't have VS 6.0 anymore) just simply disable the source control feature so it doesn't generate those .vssscc (and similar) files for source control integration.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for Git in VS 6.0, I do not even think that Git was a "thing" when VS 6.0 was released.

Is there a reason you cannot use the free VS 2015 Community version. It does support Git. Also VS Code is fairly nice and supports Git as well.

Comment: It can be a large task to upgrade VB6 code to VB 2015. Although VS Code probably is quite nice as a general-purpose editor, the VB6 IDE will be preferable for VB6 code because of the integrated debugging, context-sensitive help etc.