# Which files of VB 5.0 project can I ignore with git?

Tags: git, vb5

I want to use `git` for version control of VB 5.0.
There are many files under the project and I suppose there're some files that **should be ignored**.
[This link](https://github.com/niaomingjian/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) provides the .gitignore file for VisualStudio. I'm **not sure** if it fits VB 5.0.
**Especially**, I'm not sure whether `.vbw` and `.log` under the project should be ignored.
Could you give me some explanation about those extension files?

Comment: This is not specific to git - you might want to revise your question to make it generally about VB5 and source control of any type. Most source control systems have something equivalent to .gitignore in my experience.

Comment: This [link](http://guy_campbell.fastmail.fm/ProjFiles-vb6.htm) explained what the VB project files are. In my opinion, you can ingnore `.vbw` files.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?206500-vbw-file) regarding `vbw` files:

> It holds the positions of each window in a project's VB environment (and whether you've got it them open or not).
>
> You can delete it and when you reopen your associated project all windows are closed.

Generally, any file generated (like [those listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34729285/6309)), or with local information (like your own Windows positions) should be ignored: they are relevant only for you.