# VB6 code management tool

Tags: vb6

Earlier, I am working on a VB6 project so all development managed by me only but now a new member joined the same project. Please help me to know any code management tool so we can both can do development in same project but on different modules(Check In/Check out).(For Example: Microsoft Visual SourceSafe Code Management tool used for development in Visual Studio)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any version control system: Subversion, Git... even Visual Source Safe (although I recommend avoiding that one). Just remember that some VB6 files are binary and [cannot be merged easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322488/how-do-you-deal-with-visual-basic-6-frm-and-frx-files-in-source-control).

- Here's the Stackoverflow [Subversion advice for VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680/using-subversion-with-visual-basic-6).
- Here's the Stackoverflow [Git advice for VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462480/using-git-with-vb6).